# A US English riddle: My name is a state that is not my state. When I am downtrodden, my oppressors take risks

Tags: riddle, language, regional-dialects

I came up with this riddle a few days ago. It's my very first riddle, so it shouldn't be too hard to crack.

The two hints are:

1. My name is a state that is not my state.
2. When I am downtrodden, my oppressors take risks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

An answer that fits is:

> Gas (gasoline). Its state is liquid although its name is gas. If people step on it, they are in risk of exploding if there is a nearby spark/flame.

Comment: +1 for the answer not being a U.S. state, yet still fitting the "US English" requirement (since gas is called "petrol" in other parts of the world).

Comment: Excellent answer, except that hint 2 refers to a colloquialism rather than what you described.

Comment: Actually it's a US idiom, not a colloquialism :)

Comment: As in 'step on the gas'?

Comment: @waxwing that definitely works, although it seems like that colloquialism would only be able to be come up with after the fact (so not a good hint to the answer)

Comment: @Quark Not necessarily. My first thought upon seeing the second hint was an idiom about standing, stepping, or walking on something. I was going along the lines of stepping on toes, walking a tightrope, or standing on thin ice, but I was on the right track.

Comment: You got it, @waxwing :-)

Answer (score 5):

> I think that **Tony Montana** is the answer.
>  
>  Thanks to the first hint, we know that the answer's name is a state. The title of the question completes this hint: we can deduce that the answer's name is a state of the United States of America, and that the answer is the name of a person.
>  
>  The second hint tells us that it's risky to oppress that person, so that person may have enough influence to become dangerous.
>  Presidents and mafia have enough influence to do this.
>  
>  [Tony Montana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tony_Montana) is the protagonist of *Scarface*, and is one of the most famous mafia characters.
>  He's from Cuba, and Scarface takes place in Florida, California and New York: none of them is Montana, so the first hint is verified.

Comment: That's quite clever, but it ignores a very important hint from the title of the riddle. It only works in US English...